# Dynamic SQL sp_executesql problem

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @sync_table_name nvarchar(500)
SET @sync_table_name = 'ContactTypes'

DECLARE @sync_batch_size bigint
SET @sync_batch_size = 2

DECLARE @sync_last_received_anchor timestamp
SET @sync_last_received_anchor = 1

DECLARE @sync_max_received_anchor timestamp
SET @sync_max_received_anchor = 18732866

DECLARE @sync_new_received_anchor timestamp
DECLARE @sync_batch_count int

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500)
SET @sql = 'SELECT cast([version] as bigint) as [version], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CAST([version] as BIGINT)) as RowNumber 
INTO #Temp FROM '+@sync_table_name+' WHERE [version] > @min AND [version] <= @max ORDER BY [version];  

SET @batchCountOUT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp) / @batchSize; 
IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp) >= @batchSize) 
    SELECT @newAnchorOUT = #Temp.[version] FROM #Temp WHERE RowNumber = @batchSize;

IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp) < @batchSize) 
    SELECT @newAnchorOUT = #Temp.[version] FROM #Temp WHERE RowNumber = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp);

DROP TABLE #Temp'

DECLARE @sqlParam NVARCHAR(500)
SET @sqlParam = '@batchSize bigint, @min timestamp, @max timestamp, @newAnchorOUT timestamp OUTPUT, @batchCountOUT int OUTPUT'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @sqlParam, @batchSize = @sync_batch_size, @min = @sync_last_received_anchor, @max = @sync_max_received_anchor, @newAnchorOUT = @sync_new_received_anchor OUTPUT, @batchCountOUT = @sync_batch_count OUTPUT


            SELECT @sync_new_received_anchor, @sync_batch_count
```

It's always complaining about Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

BUT If I remove the second IF statement everything works ... is there something strange with sp_executesql and IF statements

Comment: Just an aside: I see 4 uses of `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp)`. Why not put that count into a variable after your insert and use the variable everywhere else?

Comment: And following on from Joe's point you could populate that variable by setting it to the value of @@rowcount immediately after the insert.

Comment: Thanks guys, i did the rowcount but other issue came so I tried different thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `@sql` value is more than 500 characters long. Increase the variable size.

Comment: thanks! wasted so many hours on this ... thought that the query was wrong

Answer (score 2):

your @sql= 716 characters. Just make it nvarchar(4000) and that way you will be safe